# Python Appending print output to a text file - Int vs str

Tags: python

New on here, just wondered if somebody can point me in the right direction. I have an output from a query input going to a funtion choices(ncode), where ncode is the query input. I am also opening and reading a text file and if the result of query is in this file, I am then printing it out. What I want to do is take that print output and append it to the same file, but increment (iterate) the number each time so if it finds 1, it will output what the line 1 contains and in the text file append an incremented number with the same line in the text file to show it has been accessed. Tried to create new function but continuoulsy running into issues with int and str type mismatch, any way to do it.

```
def readcode():
        fh = open("diagnose2.txt", "r")
        return fh.readlines()

def choices(ncode):
        for i, c in enumerate(readcode()):
               if ncode in c:
                        print(c, end=" ")
```

tried the: sys.stdout=open("diagnose2.txt","a") with print to print into the new file but struggling to iterate the values and then with int vs str values.

Comment: If you give us example input(s) (minimal) and desired results it helps a lot.

Comment: if ncode is an integer, you'll have to do this: `if str(ncode) in c:`

Comment: The typical input is as follows:

Comment: The typical input is taken from a simple query input string [1,2,3,4,5] as follows: if query.find ("1") >-1: choices("1") which then feeds into the fundtion  above. Problem is where the print out would look like:                 1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx       from print (c, end = " ") above, how do I then take this output and append it to the same diagnose2.txt file with a new number which is incremented to something like                   1.1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx   - seems I cant work a way to then write the output of the print (c, end = " ") to file with new number and no int vs str mismatch.